# write() with ttyS is non block

Tags: c, linux, tty

My question is this - how can you make a call write() in uCLinux 2.6.21 synchronous, ie that the call is not completed before the end of the send?
Now I have the following code:

```
//...
fd = open (PORT, O_RDWR | O_SYNC)
//...

FIO3CLR |= 0x30000000; // RTS = 0 (enable transfer)
write (fd, "A", 1) // pass
FIO3SET |= 0x30000000; // RTS = 1 (disable transfer)
```

command `FIO3SET |= 0x30000000;` starts executed almost immediately after calling the `write()`, for the task it is undesirable.
Thanks.

Comment: I think `O_SYNC` is only meaningful for disk files, not other I/O streams.

Comment: You did not define what `FIO3CLR` is.

Comment: Since you claim to be using Linux, I suspect `FIO3SET |= 0x30000000;` does not make any sense. Should you not be calling `ioctl()` or similar function to handle the serial line TTY?

Comment: Barmar, you absolutly right.

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch, it's define in #include <lpc22xx.h> at top of file

Comment: @user2214381: Why is it "undesirable" that the code executes fast?

Comment: FIO3CLR |= 0x30000000; writes '1' clear bit 28 and 29.

Comment: FIO3SET |= 0x30000000; writes '1' set bit 28 and 29

Comment: @user2214381: That does not answer my question, I think.

Comment: wilx, sorry for my english) i use google translate.  
'undesirable' replace 'wrong'

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should be setting TTY attributes and that Linux kernel will do the RTS/CTS handling for if you set the attributes. For complete example see http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html. I would guess that the part that answers your question is this:

```
newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD; // CRTSCTS is set here
//...
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);
```

Comment: wilx, Thank you for your comment.
My controller has 4 uart port, and only one of them (uart1) has hardware support for RTS/CTS and he is used to another task. In current task, I use port without hardware support RTS\CTS, so include these flags is hardly advisable.

Answer (score 0):

tcdrain() waits until all output written to the object referred to by fd has been transmitted.
it solved my problem
[C read call blocking on serial port operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396255/c-read-call-blocking-on-serial-port-operation?rq=1)